# Need to include a variable in a function of a query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have something like this:

```
$configurations = Configs:all();

foreach($configs as $config){

$documents = document::whereHas('user', function ($q) {
$q->where("portal_id", $config->id),})->get()

...
}
```

This does not work because `$config` is not defined in the query function.

How do I put the `$config->id` object there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure encapsulates its scope, meaning that it has no access to the scope in which it is defined or executed. It is, however, possible to inherit variables from the parent scope (where the closure is defined) into the closure with the use keyword:

```
$documents = document::whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($config) {
$q->where("portal_id", $config->id),})->get()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the scope of variable with `use()`

```
 $documents = document::whereHas('user', function ($q) use($config->id) {
    $q->where("portal_id", $config->id),})->get()

    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can write like this, no need to write foreach loop:

```
$configurations = Configs:all();
$documents = Document::whereHas('user', function($q) use($configurations) {
    $q->whereIn('portal_id', $configurations->pluck('id'));       
});
```

Comment: Any special reason why you do not define `$configurations` inside the closure? Just curious